# Insert value to existing collection in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a Mongo DB table **Notes** with following structure

```
Id(autoincrement value)
UserId
Notes(Collection)
```

And now i need to add one more record into that existing Notes collection. How do i do it in Mongo DB using Mongo DB driver?

In my repository i tried something like following, but its not working

```
public NoteUser AddNote(string userId, Note note)
{
    var filters = Builders<NoteUser>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.UserId, userId);
    context.Notes.InsertOne(filter,note);
}
```

How do i insert a new record to existing collection in Mongo DB table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer which i was looking for. for achieving above i need to write 
something similar to this

```
studentsCol.UpdateOneAsync(
Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, studentId),
Builders<Student>.Update.Push(x => x.MarkList, newMark));
```